# Why my app is crashing only on Huawei device but working fine on rest of the devices?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am having a very weird problem. Yesterday, my app was working fine and it was installing properly on different devices. But I don't know why this is happening. I am installing the same app I am facing this below error :

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.huawei.lcagent.client.LogCollectManager.getUserType()' on a null object reference
```

One thing I would like to mention is that it is giving this exception only in Huawei device model is ALE-L21 and the OS is 6.0 and i tried with other devices like motorola, it is working fine. My question is when I changed nothing why does it behaves like this on huawei device while it is working fine on rest of the devices?

One more thing I have just noticed that crash log is also showing below point.What does that mean?

```
E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588023/unable-to-start-android-app-due-to-logcollectmanager-getusertype-error

Comment: Are you using any hardware component in your App? like(Bluetooth, Gps, Camera)

Comment: @JohnJoe I have already tried that .that did not work for me

Comment: @Mohammadnabil yes I am accessing camera in my app. Is that a problem

Comment: try [this](http://www.androidstar.cn/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-int-com-huawei-lcagent-client-logcollectmanager-getusertype/)

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem but in my case i have used package identifier of already installed app and that conflict with each others so application is not able to installed.

Check your package identifier in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Resource Hooks either have to be disabled or Huawei Theme Engine has to be turned off for the framework to be active. I think the issue is pretty much resolved then.

Try turning off the Huawai Theme engine and re run it,it should start working

Comment: how to turn off theme engine? what is theme enging?

Comment: disable Huawei theme engine by editing this line 

ro.config.hwtheme=0

can be found in:

system/emui/base/prop/local.prop